# Should I use fputs or putchar?

Tags: c, string, loops, multidimensional-array, fputs

Here is my following program. I don't want a new line, which is why I used `fputs()` instead of `puts()`

```
char words[5][6] = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
   fputs(words[i], stdout);
```

I was wondering if this line of code is safe enough to use as an alternative to this code.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
   if (words[i][j] != NULL)
      putchar(words[i][j]);
   else
      continue;
}
```

Note: I'm aware the loop on the second code section needs a little work, particularly on the if statement, but I was wondering about the output overall. I'm asking this question, because on my very first question, I used `gets()` and was told not to. So I wanted to avoid bad keywords so to speak.

Comment: It is safe enough and much simpler than the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use fputs or putchar?

I would recommend that you use `fputs` for your purpose because it achieves your objective without needing to reinvent the wheel.

Your second approach with `putchar` will also work but again why to reinvent the wheel? However if you must use `putchar` for some reasons, you need to replace `continue` with `break` to break out of the inner loop on encountering a `null character` which marks the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`gets` is inherently unsafe (and was in turn removed from C standard in 2011), `fputs` is not. I see nothing wrong with your code that uses `fputs`.

Answer (score 0):

`fputs` is safe to use.  `gets` is, as you said, no good.

Answer (score 0):

`puts` and `fputs` are both safe in that context. Your alternative is just a (bad) C translation of `fputs`. It is wrong because you continue the loop after a null character. If for any reason, garbage (from a previous longer string) exists after first null, you would use it.

And anyway, functions from the standard library might by optimized, so you should use them when possible.